# Compile a C++11 program for an older Linux

Tags: c++, linux

I have written a C++ program and I used some of the C++11 features. That is not a problem since I have a recent `g++` and `clang++` on my system. Now I would like to run this on other computers that have older versions of Ubuntu or other distributions on them.

To make it even worse, I have dependencies to Boost, json, crypto++ and other libraries.

Is there some way to get this to work on a non C++11 system, or do I have to rewrite this as C++98?

Comment: how about compiling your own boost, json and clang++ on the older ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just link it statically. There are static versions of `libstdc++`, `boost` and other libararies in Ubuntu repos. You can compile your binaries on C++11 system and then copy them to C++98 one. They won't have dependency on C++11 version of `libstdc++`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want/need to compile your code on an older distribution you'll need to provide alternate code that doesn't use C++11 features.

If you just need the finished product available, it's possible that you could cross-compile on your c++11 compiler and generate a binary that would be compatible with the other distributions you wish to support.

Answer (score 1):

Just copy all the libraries you need over to your old system. Set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before calling your progamm to select your version of th libraries in stead of the builtin ones.